# PHP Notice: Undefined variable: http_type

Tags: php, opencart, vqmod

I get the following PHP Notice in my opencart log file.

> `Undefined variable: http_type in /home/AAA/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_view_theme_template_product_product.tpl on line 3`

Here is what I have in my `product.php` file's few first few lines

```
<?php if (isset($this->request->server['HTTPS']) && (($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == '1'))) {
    $http_type = "https:";} else {$http_type = "http:";} 
<!---THIS IS LINE 3--->  ?>    
    <?php echo $header; ?><?php echo $column_left; ?><?php echo $column_right; ?>
    <div id="content"><?php echo $content_top; ?> 
      <div class="breadcrumb" xmlns:v="<?php echo $http_type;?>//rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#" id="brd-crumbs"  >     
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
                <li typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
                <?php echo $breadcrumb['separator']; ?><a property="v:title" rel="v:url" href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><span><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></span></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Have you done any initial trouble-shooting? Tracked down the variable and where it should get set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it's just a notice so I expect everything is working as you would expect.

The notice is generated because when the `$http_type` variable is echoed, it hasn't necessarily been set to anything.  If you add `$http_type = '';` before the initial `if` statement, that will get rid of the notice.

Comment: shouldn't matter. php's variable scope is function-level. both paths of the if() are setting a value, so no matter what the if() evaluates to, the variable's going to get something set.